# Paramiko for ssh -p 10002 ubuntu@127.0.0.1

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

how to do ssh for `ssh -p 10002 root@127.0.0.1`in paramiko?

```
ssh.connect("how to give here")
```

what command i should use to pass in `ssh.connent()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this

```
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1',10002,username='root',password='root')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh.connect("location", username="user", password="pswd")
```

location is usually a web address "example.com" but can point locally also.
http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.3/index.html